# let dataset.getYMax return zero in case there are no items in the dataset instead of -infinity - anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm adding data to `dataset` when a condition is `true`, then I'm using `getYMax()` to calculate the maximum value in the dataset. However, if the `dataset` is empty (no items have been collected) it will return `-infinity`. Is there any way to make `getYMax()` return `0` instead of `-infinity`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use a separate function returning a double and taking the dataset as an argument, call it `f_getDSMax()`:

```
if (myDataSet.size() == 0) {
    return 0.;
}
return myDataSet.getYMax();
```

Or you do it in 1 line:

```
myDataSet.size() == 0 ? 0. : myDataSet.getYMax()
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Benjamin for your answer, this is what I have done and you confirmed it is the right approach.

Comment: Cool. But do always mention what you have already tried, saves us work :)

Comment: Sorry I tried to use the If function after I added the question, but I thought it was not the correct approach (even if it was working). Will do in future for sure thank you for your advice.